# How to implement a for loop inside a for loop inside a for loop?

Tags: python, loops, equality, equation

I have two variables **(n;p)** in two independent equations, one to find **C** and the other to find **T**. For the first iteration I assume the values of **n** and **p** finding **C** and **T**, now I have to find all the pairs of **n** and **p** that will make **C=T**.
Additionally to being used as a constant, **n** will define the range for a list in the first equation and **C** is the sum of all the values on that list.

I was able to program the first iteration defining **n** and **p** as constants, thus finding **C** and **T** which were not equal to each other, but I don't know how to program the whole process so that it will repeat for a fix set of **p** (that will be a list and not a constant) and finding the **n**'s that will make **C=T**. I have to iterate through **p** and for each one find one **n** that will satisfy the condition.
Therefore I need to make a **for loop** inside a **for loop** inside a **for loop**. It will be something like this:

```
for all the values of p in range (0, 12, 0.1) do:
     for all the values of n in range(0, 160, 0.001) do:
             "the rest of the operation that also has for loop in it"
```

that operation will result in **C** and **T**, then,

```
if C = T
print(p and n)  # the pair (p;n) that made it possible
```

As you can see that's an idea, not actual code, I don't know how to write the actual code for it. I saw something about a **zip** function but still don't get it. Help.

Comment: It's hard to help you because the problem description is too abstract, but I think you need to follow a tutorial and make sure you understand the fundamentals.

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out by trying to enunciate the question (and making some research):

```
p = np.arange(0.1, 12.1, 0.1)  
for k in range(0, p.size):
# this will evaluate the next "for loop" (iterate with k) for all the values of p
    n = np.arange(0, 160, 0.002)
    for j in range(0, n.size):
    # this will evaluate the next "for loop" (iterate with j) for all the values of n  
        # the next for loop uses "i" to iterate other operations not relevant for 
        # this problem right now
```

Inside of the "for loop" that uses "j", at the end, I needed to compare the results of C and T and find if they were equal (or as equal as possible), and then print the **n** and **p** that made this posible.

I still need to work this part of the code but a simple way to compare it could be:

```
        comparison_parameter = 1
        comparison = T - C
        if comparison_parameter > comparison > -comparison_parameter:
            print('For p = ', round(p[k], 1), ', n =', round(n[j], 4))
        else:
            pass
```

This is definitely not the most elegant way to do all this, here are some problems with this code that I would recommend to improve:

- I'm using lists and not generator, therefore python will store every calculation in memory
- I'm not using "assertAlmostEqual() function" to compare C and T (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-unittest-assertalmostequal-function/)
- My way gives me multiple values of **n** (given a certain **p**) that satisfy the condition for a particular `comparison_parameter`, but I only want the one correspondant to the `comparison` being closest to 0, meaning that **C** and **T** will be closer to each other.

Comment: You can just do `for p in np.arrange(...)` instead of using `p[k]`. For the inner part, try `if abs(T - C) < 1`, and the `else: pass` does not do anything.